# heegard diagram 

Tags: heegaard-floer-homology, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

It seems like there is an algorithm to find the Heegard diagram of a 3 manifold obtained by surgery on a link. Also someone told me I can find it in the Gompf and Stipciz's book. But I could not find it. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "the Heegaard diagram"?  There are many.  Do you only want to find one, or do you want to find a special one? 

Comment: For the record, the correct spelling is "Stipsicz", and not "Stipciz".

Comment: I just want to find any heegard diagram with any genus and and any attaching curves.

Comment: I guess this person read Exercise 6.2.2 on page 210.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(1) Choose a planar presentation of your link, approximately in the plane of the blackboard.  Let $N$ be a tubular neighborhood of the link in this position.

(2) For each crossing $c$ of the presentation, add a 1-handle $T_c$ to $N$ which is perpendicular to the blackboard and connects the upper and lower parts of the crossing.  Let $H$ be the union of $N$ and all the 1-handles $T_c$.

(3) $S^3 \setminus H$ is a handlebody.  The corresponding set of Heegaard curves on $\partial H$ bijects with the complementary regions of the (flattened) planar diagram of the link.

(4) $H$ is, of course, also a handlebody.  For the corresponding Heegaard curves take the surgery curves on $N$ (this involves a choice to make them disjoint from the attaching disks of the $T_c$) union the obvious small, disk-bounding curves on the boundary of each $T_c$.  (Correction added later: Actually, if there are $k$ components of the link then one should omit $k-1$ of the $T_c$ curves.  The omitted crossings should be minimal with respect to connecting the components of the link.  Also, I'm assuming that the planar projection is a connected graph.)

Comment: This is a nice very-rough-outline! There's the "digging a trench" construction needed to prove that surgery along the curve gives rise to Dehn twists on the handlebody; you also have to do something non-trivial to deal with non-unit framings.

Comment: I agree that the outline is rough, but on the other hand the question asked for an algorithm, not a proof that the algorithm was correct. ... Actually, I don't understand your comment.  I don't think I ever have to mention or think about Dehn twists, and I think what I wrote works fine for non-unit and even non-integer surgeries.

Comment: ... Put another way, the output is a surface with two sets of curves, not two handlebodies with a homeomorphism between their boundaries.

Comment: How does this work for example for a Lens space $L(p,q)$? That's just $-p/q$-surgery on the unknot. (1) So we take $N = S^1 \times D^2 \stackrel{\text{unknot }-p/q}{\hookrightarrow} S^3$. (2) We don't need any 1-handles since there are no crossings. $H = N$. (3) I can only guess what you mean by this step. I'm drawing the circle ${0} \times \partial D^2 \subset \partial H$. (4) What exactly are the surgery curves on $N$? In particular, for general $p,q$, the curve must go around $H$ several times? I take it this is just the torus knot?

Comment: In the lens space example, the two curves of the Heegaard diagram are (1) a $-p/q$ curve on $\partial N$, and (2) a curve which bounds a disk in $S^3\setminus N$, i.e. a longitude.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about Gompf and Stipsicz, but the algorithm to obtain a Heegaard diagram from a surgery presentation may be found for example in [A Simple Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Kirby Calculus on Links](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2154000?uid=3738992&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21101302227937) by Ning Lu, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. Vol 331(1) pp. 143-156 (1992). It's not difficult, and it's worth knowing.